# DiscretizeGraphics on a RegionDifference not returning a MeshRegion

Tags: regions, mesh, discretization

I want to take region difference of a sub-mesh of a Delaunay Mesh and a discretized ImplicitRegion. However, Mathematica does not recognize the return as a MeshRegion. Moreover, Discretizing the returned result does not yield a Mesh region. I am attaching a sample code below that illustrates this.

First I define a discretized implicit region.

```
reg=DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[-2 < x < 2 && -2 < y < 2, {x,y}]];
```

Then I take a list of random points in a subregion -2 < x,y < -1.

```
testReg = RandomReal[{-2, -1}, {10^4, 2}];
```

I now take a sub-mesh of the delaunaymesh of the above list of points (testReg).

```
d = .03;
mesh=MeshRegion[testReg,Select[MeshCells[DelaunayMesh[testReg],2],(EuclideanDistance[testReg[[#[[1,1]]]],testReg[[#[[1,2]]]]]<d&&EuclideanDistance[testReg[[#[[1,1]]]],testReg[[#[[1,3]]]]]<d&&EuclideanDistance[testReg[[#[[1,2]]]],testReg[[#[[1,3]]]]]<d)&]];
```

Now, I have two mesh regions reg and mesh of which I want to take the difference. I define

```
regDif = RegionDifference[reg, mesh];
```

This is a region however not a mesh region. RegionQ on regDif returns true. MeshRegionQ does not. Moreover, DiscretizeRegion[regDif] does not return a mesh region either.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

**Edit**: I am on version 10.0.0. This issue is absent in version 11.3

Comment: If I recall correctly, this should work with version 11.2 or higher (I tested it with 11.3).

Comment: Thank you. I am on version 10.0.0. I think that is the problem.

Comment: @HimalayaSenapati If you wrap your entire call in `CloudEvaluate`, you'll get a remote kernel on 11.3 to do this for you.

Comment: On v10.4: `Head@regDif` yields `BoundaryMeshRegion`; `MeshRegionQ@regDif` indeed gives `False`, but `MeshRegionQ@DiscretizeRegion@regDif` returns `True`.